# Woocommerce variation title editor admin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, editor, title, product-variations

I use WooCommerce and I'm able to display the variations on shop/archive. What I want is to change the title/name for each variation which in back end doesn't have. It's only sku, images,etc NO title. How can I add field for title?

[image: Screenshot here]

Comment: Ok i solve it already. using this:
woocommerce_product_after_variable_attributes & woocommerce_save_product_variation with custom meta.

Comment: You can add an answer to your own question. it could help someone else

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by adding custom HTML in `woocommerce_product_after_variable_attributes` action

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_after_variable_attributes', function( $loop, $variation_data, $variation ) { ?>
    <div>
        <p class="form-row form-row-full">
            <label>Variation Title</label>
            <input type="text" name="variable_post_title[<?php echo $loop; ?>]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $variation->post_title ); ?>" placeholder="Variation title">
        </p>
    </div><?php
}, 10, 3 );
```

and then save the post title in `woocommerce_save_product_variation`

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_product_variation', function() {
    if ( 'variable' !== $_POST['product-type'] ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( ! isset( $_POST['variable_post_title'][ $i ] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $variation_post_title = wc_clean( $_POST['variable_post_title'][ $i ] );

    wp_update_post( [
        'ID' => $variation_id,
        'post_title' => $variation_post_title,
    ] );

    clean_post_cache( $variation_id );
}, 10, 2 );
```